# Can I add observer to "zoom" property of GMSMapView()?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I want to add an observer on zoom (Float) property of GMSMapView. I wonder if it is possible and how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ya go :)

```
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

extension GMSMapView {
    public var rx_zoom: Observable<Float> {
        return self.rx_observe(Float.self, "camera.zoom")
                   .filter { $0 != nil }
                   .map { $0! }
    }
}
```

voilà !

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought that nobody would answer me and had to use KVO instead. But as I use RxSwift through the whole project this looks like more elegant solution :)

Comment: Join RxSwift's slack channel :) You will get responses much faster and more accurate than that of stackoverflow :)